# Django - How to pass a form instance from one view to another

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a form with multi steps in it. First part uses a `forms.ModelForm`, once completed, the user is re-directed to another view with a `forms.Form` in it.

Ideally, I would like to save the first form only if the secondary form is valid and save them both at the same time if that's the case.

I usually use self.request.session to pass data from one view to another, but a form's instance is `not serializable`, hence, can not append it to the session.

As an example:

`FirstView` contains `FirstForm` with fields ('firstname', 'lastname')

`SecondView` contains `SecondForm` with fields ('address', 'gender')

```
If FirstForm and SecondForm is valid
  form1.save
  form2.save
```

Would anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: A [form wizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can store form's cleaned_data in django session and pass it to another form as initial. For example:

```
def first_view(request):
   form = FirstForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
       request.session['first_form'] = form.cleaned_data
       return redirect('to_second_view')

def second_view(request):
     form = SecondForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        first_form_data = request.session.pop('first_form',{})
        first_form_instance = FirstFormModel.objects.create(**first_form_data)
        second_form_instance = form.save()
     # rest of the code...
```

Comment: But the first form doesn't need to be edited, just saved if the second form is also valid. To keep it clean, wouldn't it be nicer to just call form.instance.save on the first form if the second form is also valid? I will edit my question as it's lacking information. Sorry about that.

Comment: well, you have all the data you need in second_view for creating the form instance. I have updated the answer. please have a look

Comment: That's actually a pretty good solution. However, the first form has 3 foreign keys in it and those seem to also be `unserializable` (Object of type My_Model is not JSON serializable). I guess I could also pass the pk of those foreign keys and recreate the form, but is there a cleaner solution? Because that's 3 more SQL queries if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This solution only works if all of the form data is JSON serializable so it won't work for any form that has a field that is model-based, a datetime object etc.